# Selecting AVG for x days for each row

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I'm trying to calculate 2 running averages from a simple price table. In the following table there is a date and a price.

```
Pricedate   Price
01/10/2018  1
28/09/2018  3
27/09/2018  5
26/09/2018  4
25/09/2018  8
24/09/2018  4
21/09/2018  6
20/09/2018  2
19/09/2018  1
18/09/2018  0
```

For every date I want to calculate the moving 2 days and 5 days average like.

```
Pricedate   Price   Average2    Average5
01/10/2018  1       4           4
28/09/2018  3       7           5
27/09/2018  5       7           5
26/09/2018  4       10          5
25/09/2018  8       8           4
24/09/2018  4       8           3
21/09/2018  6       5           2
20/09/2018  2       2           1
19/09/2018  1       1           0
18/09/2018  0       0           0
```

I have tried the following but i does not return the average correctly.

```
SELECT *, DATE_SUB(Pricedate, INTERVAL 5 DAY_HOUR) AS Days, AVG(price) 
AS Average2
FROM prices
GROUP BY Days
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks - but could you please explain me what more is needed in the simple question above?

Comment: I'm satisfied that the accepted answer to the linked question is entirely self-explanatory.

Comment: Sorry - I have no idea what you are talking about , but thanks for the help

Comment: @Manivestor Your averages in expected output table are not making sense. For eg: at date 21/09/2018 price is 6; at date 20/09/2018  price is 2; so running 2 days average should be: (6+2)/2 = 4; but you are showing expected output as 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three ways to do this:

First one, clean and easy, but slow solution:

```
    SELECT twoday.pricedate,twoday.price,twoday.ravg as twoday,fiveday.ravg as fiveday
    FROM (
            SELECT a.Pricedate,a.Price, SUM(b.Price)/2 as ravg
            from table1 a
            LEFT join table1 b on b.Pricedate between date_SUB(a.Pricedate, interval 2 day) AND a.Pricedate
            GROUP BY a.Pricedate
            ORDER BY a.Pricedate
        ) twoday
    JOIN (
            SELECT a.Pricedate,SUM(b.Price)/5 AS ravg //
            FROM table1 a
            LEFT JOIN table1 b ON b.Pricedate BETWEEN DATE_SUB(a.Pricedate, INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND a.Pricedate
            GROUP BY a.Pricedate
            ORDER BY a.Pricedate
        ) fiveday ON fiveday.pricedate=twoday.pricedate
```

Basically what we do here is for every row of the original table we join N rows from that table again, where N is the time window we're using. Then we group them back together to calculate aggregate values.

Second approach is to use a buffer, but since there is no arrays in mysql, we need to use multiple variables. It looks ugly, but it's much faster since we're only selecting each row once.

```
SELECT Pricedate,Price,twoday,fiveday
FROM (
    SELECT Pricedate,Price,
    @5dayago:= @4dayago,
    @4dayago:= @3dayago,
    @3dayago:= @2dayago,
    @2dayago:= @1dayago,
    @1dayago:= a.Price,
    (@2dayago + @1dayago)/2 AS twoday,
    (@5dayago + @4dayago + @3dayago + @2dayago + @1dayago)/5 AS fiveday
    FROM table1 a,
    (SELECT @5dayago:=5, @4dayago:=0, @3dayago:=0, @2dayago:=0, @1dayago:=0) b
    ORDER BY a.Pricedate
) c
```

Also note that this approach cannot handle skipped days properly

And the third way is to just do this at your backend/endpoint, here's an example in php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$buffer=array_fill(0, 5, 0);
$sql = "SELECT Pricedate,Price FROM table1 ORDER BY Pricedate";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$data=[];
$lastdate=null;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($lastdate===null)
        $lastdate=new DateTimeImmutable($row["Pricedate"]);
    else{
        //try to fill buffer with zeroes for every missing day
        $newdate=new DateTimeImmutable($row["Pricedate"]);
        $interval=$lastdate->diff($newdate)->days;
        for($i=1;$i<$interval;$i++){
            array_unshift($buffer,0);
            array_pop($buffer);
        }
        $lastdate=$newdate;
    }
    array_unshift($buffer,$row["Price"]); //add new price into buffer
    array_pop($buffer); //and throw out the oldest one
    $row["fivedays"]=array_sum($buffer)/5;
    $row["twodays"]=array_sum(array_slice($buffer,0,2))/2;
    $data[] = $row;
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been looking a long time for a simpler solution, but cannot get it working. The first solution does not work if there are "holes" in the dataset - for instance in my table there is no data for weekends, and hence the average will not be correct-

Comment: @Manivestor It assumes price to be 0 at days that are missing from dataset. What kind of behaviour are you expecting for those gaps? If you want to skip them, as if they never existed at all, you'll need to use a different column instead of date (e.g. row id, assuming there are no gaps) or use MySQL CURSOR.